# Convert PSD files to Android XML

Tags: android, android-layout, psd

Is there any open source tool which takes the PSD layer (.PSD) and creates layout in XML automatically.
I tried with Zepline online service

Comment: `Is there any open source tool which`... we don't deal with recommendations for libraries/frameworks here

Comment: @a_local_nobody  If you know anything about this please let me know?

Comment: this site doesn't allow questions asking for off-site resources, such as libraries or tools

Comment: Similar to Zepline https://exportkit.com/learn/how-to/export-your-psd/convert-a-psd-to-android-xml-ui-and-java